# How can I import data in Solr directly from file and not using curl / Http protocol?

Tags: http, solr, dataimporthandler

I have to import lot of data in my Solr (4.1.3) core. I can do it with a customized requestHandler called by curl with an http call (with full-import parameter).

But that gets me an http time-out because there's a lot of data.

As my import files and the Solr server are in the same machine, Solr could use directly disk files and not pass thru http protocol.

Is this possible ? it seems you can talk to Solr only by http.

Thank you for answer (if there is any !)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RemoteStreaming](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ContentStream#RemoteStreaming), which allows you to give Solr either an url (`stream.url`) or a path to a local file (`stream.file`) that it should import.

Be advised that if you have untrusted users accessing your Solr server or are able to manipulate the URL directly, this might allow them to read any file that Solr has access to (or launch a DDoS if you allow them to directly manipulate the stream.url parameter). If you have a public facing Solr server you do however have larger issues that can be a problem :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, but are you sure it changes something, as you still use http protocol ? If you simply stream from the disk to the POST stream, the problem stays. I suspect it would be necessary to use Solr Java classes directly.

Comment: The stream.file parameter tells Solr to read the data directly from the local disk, and not through HTTP. You have to tell Solr to read the data somehow, and doing it through HTTP is as good anything. There is also embedded solr which might allow you to create a internal Solr instance and then replace the files into your regular Solr server later. Doing stream.file is however easier and cleaner if it works.